# Express $x^3+3x^2-2x+1$ in the form $ax^3+b(x-1)^2+cx+d$.

Tags: polynomials

> Express $x^3+3x^2-2x+1$ in the form $ax^3+b(x-1)^2+cx+d$.

I have no idea what the question is asking. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: The problem is asking you to find real numbers $a,b,c$ and $d$ such that $$\forall x\in \mathbb R\left(x^3+3x^2-2x+1=ax^3+b(x-1)^2+cx+d\right).$$

Answer (score 3):

$$x^3+3x^2-2x+1=x^3+3(x^2-2x+1)+6x-3-2x+1$$
$$x^3+3(x-1)^2+4x-2$$